# Custom domain from google not routing to App engine site

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain

Purchased a domain from Google domains and updated settings of my App engine application to add my domain as a Custom domain.
My App engine App link: http://fooapp.appspot.com. Verified that actual link works.

1. From console.cloud.google.com ->AppEngine->Settings->Custom Domains

verified custom domain ( foobar.com )

2. "Point your domain to fooapp" (Step-2)
3. Configure resources and Done
   Even after 48hours (wait period for dns propogation), when I launch http://www.foobar.com or http://foobar.com or http://www.sub.foobar.com, I do not see my app engine site. It redirects to http://www.dnsrsearch.com.   
   **nslookup foobar.com** shows "*Can't find foobar.com: No answer*"

What am I missing?
Below is the summary of listings I see under Custom Domains tab in console.cloud.google.com
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to resolve it following steps in [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application)
I had to add **Custom resource records** under my custom domain's DNS on http://domains.google.com